# Why does my Excel VBA macro take so long to run?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

My macro takes x and y coordinates from several sheets and plots them on a chart, all of which are in the same workbook. The code runs just fine and charts the data on the first sheet almost instantaneously, but it takes literally minutes to add data from other sheets to the chart. Can someone suggest why it takes so long to run, and what I can do to speed it up? Thanks!

The code starts by creating a sheet named "Chart", and then plots x and y data onto the chart from the sheet named "Cluster 1". This is the part that runs almost instantaneously. The code then takes x and y data from sheets named "Cluster 2", "Cluster 3", etc. This is the part that takes minutes to run.

```
Public Sub MakeClusterChart()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Chart"
    Sheets("Chart").Select
    ClusterPtr = 1
    Sheets("Cluster " & ClusterPtr).Select
    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Cluster " & ClusterPtr & "'!$A:$B")
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Chart"
    For ClusterPtr = 2 To NumClusters
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(ClusterPtr).XValues = Range("'Cluster " & ClusterPtr & "'!$A:$A")
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(ClusterPtr).Values = Range("'Cluster " & ClusterPtr & "'!$B:$B")
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried not plotting the entire columns?